# How to reopen debugger tabs in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am in Eclipse and want to debug a program. I'm coding in Java if that helps. By default, when you enter debugger view, there are like 3 tabs, one of them is debug. They were closed somehow. How do I reopen these tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on the button that says "Debug" that you press to switch to the debug perspective, then select "reset" to set your perspective as default.

If you don't see the "debug" icon, then go to windows menu and then "open perspective", and then "others" in case it doesn't appear there

Comment: The other comment was helpful but didn't mention the reset view. Thank you also.

Answer (score 1):

On Menu bar, follow Window->Show View to see default views. To show a specific view, you may have to browse other views on Window->Show View->Others.

Comment: Thank you, I am just starting out using Stanford cs106A to teach myself and it came to the debugging lecture and my view was different. Why was my question voted down?

Comment: @mharris7190 I dont know who downvoted but your question is not very appropriate for SO. You could find your answer by googling. I suggest you to read http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 0):

*Window - Show view* is the place where you'll find all the possible views.